# How do I link to a file page?

Tags: mediawiki

I have turned on `$wgFileExtensions` for pdf and uploaded a pdf-file and now I'm trying to create a pipe link to the corresponding file page like this:

```
[[File:test.pdf|Test file]]
```

But link text is ignored so the the link text is just the same as the url:

```
File:test.pdf
```

But i try to link to a png-file like this:

```
[[File:test.png|Test file image]]
```

Then everything works fine and the link text is like expected:

```
Test file image
```

Do i need to add any changes in the config, to allow pipe links to added filetypes?

And how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link to a page in the `File` namespace, put a colon before, like this:

```
[[:File:test.pdf|Test file]]
```

Otherwise, MW will try to embed the file. This has nothing to do with the file type, and the only reason it “works” in the `test.png` example is probably that the file test.png does not exist on your wiki.

Another namespace that has a special behaviour is the Category namespace, where adding a link like `[[Category:Birds in Africa]]`, will add the current page to the category, whereas a link to the category page would need to look like this: `[[:Category:Birds in Africa]]` (or, more likely `[[:Category:Birds in Africa|Birds in Africa]]`).